# Crystal Reports - Pull record based on values in different tables

Tags: select, crystal-reports, report, record

I have a report where I am looking at an AR table to pull in billing information.  AR.CustID stores a customer # and AR.JobID stores the job number.  There is a Job table that stores a job number - Job.JobID and also a customer # at Job.CustID.  There is also a customer table that I need to match against called Cust.  The report accepts a parameter "SalesRepID" which is a 2 digit number.  When the report is generated, it should:

- Pull in the AR table record
- Look at AR.CustID and then look at Cust.CustID to find that record in Cust.
- If Cust.SalesRepID is equal to the parameter that was entered, "SalesRepID", then it should display the AR record.
- If it's not there, skip and go to the next.

Essentially, I have to look at the customer in the AR record, compare it to the Customer information and if the SalesRepID that the person generating the report entered matches the SalesRepID for the customer being looked at, it'll show the line.

TL:DR - I need to pull in AR information for customers based on who the sales rep is. When the report is run, the person enters a SalesRepID and the report should ONLY pull up AR records where the SalesRepID is attached to the customer being billed.

I hope this makes sense.  Please let me know if I can clarify anything for you.

Tried using different select record statements to match up data but not getting anywhere.